# Why different "hashing" results from two different servers on the same password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a web aplication where I can create `Tecnico`

**TecnicoController** (application web)

```
        $tecnico = new Tecnico;
        $tecnico->idTecnico = Input::get('idtecnico');
        $tecnico->Nombre = Input::get('nombre');
        $tecnico->Apellido = Input::get('apellido');
        $tecnico->Telefono = Input::get('telefono');
        $tecnico->Contrasena = Hash::make(Input::get('idtecnico'));  //<--- hash of my pass, eg pass: 12 -> hash: $12345abc
        $path = public_path().'/tecnico';
        $fotoPerfil = Input::file('imagen');
        $fotoPerfil->move($path, Input::get('idtecnico'));
        $tecnico->Foto ='/tecnico/'.$tecnico->idTecnico;
        $tecnico->save();
```

Also I have a different project, that works as a server to access the database from a mobile application. A `Tecnico` from your cell phone can access your account by entering a `contrasena` (password) and `idTecnico`(id)

**TecnicoController** (server)

```
        $idUnico = Input::get('idUnico');
        $contrasena = Hash::make(Input::get('contrasena')); //<--- hash of my pass: eg pass: 12 -> hash: $146435gzc (change)
        $tecnico = DB::table('Tecnico')->where('idTecnico', $idUnico)->where('Contrasena',  $contrasena)->first();
```

The problem happens when you enter the password from the server. The Hashin creates a different value that exists in the database (when creating a `Tecnico`).

How I can get the same hash value that is in the database?

Comment: You should use `Hash::check` instead of querying the DB for the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this easily in a query, your best bet would be to grab the user and then compare the password, like so.

```
$idUnico = Input::get('idUnico');
$tecnico = DB::table('Tecnico')->where('idTecnico', $idUnico)->first();

if($tecnico) {
    if(Hash::check(Input::get('contrasena'), $technico->Contrasena)) {
        // passwords are the same
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, work fine. Can you explain me how work the ``Hash::check`` method?

Comment: Hashes are salted but the salt is in the hash itself, basically `Hash::check()` takes the sale from the provided hash and compares, without recreating a brand new hash.